# Why are the aspect ratio of sensor size and aspect ratio of image resolution different?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm trying to understand the relationship between the focal length of a camera in mm and the focal length in pixels, and this has raised the question in my mind of why the aspect ratio of the image size and sensor size is different and what is the correct way to think about focal length in term of computer vision?

Comment: Isn't all cameras have the aspect ratio of the sensor size and the image size same?. For ex, Canon 5d sensor size is 35.8 x 23.9 mm and maximum resolution is 4,368 × 2,912 pixels, both have the aspect ratio of 1.5. This is the case for most of the cameras i know.

Answer (score 1):

Why aspect ratio of image size and sensor dimension is not necessarily the same?

Not every image sensor has square pixels. 
Some cameras don't give you all pixels in an image, they physically have.

Read this and have a look at different sensor datasheets for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio

What is the correct way to think about focal length in terms of computer vision?

Expressing focal length in pixels is just convenient for calculations. You could as well transfer every image coordinate into metric coordinates but this would require a lot more calculations compared to converting only one value from metric to pixels.

There is only one way to think of focal length in computer vision. Just make sure you understand what focal length is in optics... It's the distance between the principal plane and the focal plane in an optical system.

It is used for geometric calculations in central projection as used in many camera models.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the other answer, the image has been letterboxed.

If you find that the sensor size is 4:3 while the captured frame or image is 16:9, then obviously the lesser dimension has been trimmed.  You could compute what the "effective" sensor size would be by dividing the greater dimension of the sensor size by the quantity (16/9).